# Can't seem to use IntelliJ feature

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.1

With the new release of Android Studio 3.1, I looked at [the dev blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/android-studio-3-1.html) to see what was new. They actually added [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2017-3-java) features, including *"Chain completion aware of type casts"*.

[image]

It seems really nice but I can't manage to get this working. Can someone give me a code sample where the auto-completion actually show this new feature ? Or did I misunderstood how the hole thing works ?